# TripleDES Length of the data to encrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, encryption, 3des, tripledes

I have the following code :

```
public static string Encrypt3Des(string cipherString)
{
    string result = "";

    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] ivArray;

    byte[] toEncryptArray = Enc3DesPerChar(cipherString);
    //string toEncryptString = ByteArrayToString(toEncryptArray);

    // Get the key from config file
    System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
    string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));
    string iv = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("InitializationVector", typeof(String));

    keyArray = StringToByteArray(key);
    ivArray = StringToByteArray(iv);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm

    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    tdes.IV = ivArray;

    //ChiperMode
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    //PaddingMode(if any extra byte added)
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    //transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor
    tdes.Clear();

    result = ByteArrayToString(resultArray);

    return result;
}
```

And this is my method :

```
protected static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}

protected static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}

protected static byte[] Enc3DesPerChar(String toEncrypt)
{
    string toAsciiString = ByteArrayToString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncrypt));

    string toRoll = toAsciiString;

    int NumberChars = toRoll.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(toRoll.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Everything works fine with the above method until I found that the method cannot accept less than 8 character.

The block code that raise an error :

```
byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
```

Error message :

> Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.

Example input :

```
Encrypt3Des("14022000"); // return encrypt because 8 character or more

Encrypt3Des("1402200"); // return error because 7 character
```

Does anybody know why this is or how I can fix it? (I don't know if it comes from my encrypting method, but I know a web app which uses the exact same thing to encrypt strings and that one does work.)

EDIT :
The tool that I used for manual encrypt : [3des](http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/)

The option must :

- Text input type
- Plaintext input text
- 3DES function
- CBC mode
- Fixed Key Hex
- Fixed Init Vector

Comment: You have to use padding for this cipher in this mode (CBC).

Comment: 3DES is a block cipher, in CBC mode it can encrypt data only in multiples of 8 bytes, if you want to use it to encrypt data with a length that is not a multiple of 8 bytes, then you must use padding, with the caveat that your encrypted data may then be longer than your input data by up to 8 bytes.

Comment: **Do not use 3DES for new work**, it is not as secure as AES and only has 112-bit security with a triple key, instead use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) which supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits.

Comment: You turn your string into bytes (good) to turn it into hex (huh?) to turn it back into bytes (?!).  Steps two and three there could be removed.  But then you're trying to do 3DES on a character at a time.  And that's pretty darn weird.  You want PKCS7 padding and to just throw the whole byte array at `TransformFinalBlock`.  It'll come out to ((inputBytes.Length + 15) / 8) * 8)` bytes.  (0 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 16, 15 -> 16, 16 -> 24, etc)

Comment: This is the tools that I used for manual encrypt [link](http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/) , the app doesn't reveal any Padding option and my client using this tool to encrypt with PHP CI language. So what should I do to revise my code and the result can be same as the tool ? The option must be Plain Input Text, 3des function, CBC mode, fixed Hex Key, and fixed IV.

Answer (score 2):

You are using padding as none.  Set the padding mode to `PKCS7`.

Comment: If I use padding mode to PKCS7, the result will always return me encrypted string more than I expected.

Comment: Yes, the encrypted data will be up to one block longer, 8 bytes for DES/3DES.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think just found the solution (my client told me how), I need to fill up the character with null before the loop. null can be converted to ascii with "00". so I decide to PadRight to the ascii result with '0' to 16 character, so one of my method become :

```
protected static byte[] Enc3DesPerChar(String toEncrypt)
{
    string toAsciiString = ByteArrayToString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncrypt));

    string toRoll = toAsciiString.PadRight(16,'0');

    int NumberChars = toRoll.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(toRoll.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Using null padding is a poor idea.

Comment: And if you want to use this padding, it's easier to just change PaddingMode to `Zeros`.  But zero-padding cannot be removed by the decryptor, it's up to the recipient to understand if the trailing zeros are semantic or not.